# Is it possible to express the area of the intersection of 2 circles as a closed-form expression?

Tags: geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The cow in the field problem (intersecting circular areas)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51/the-cow-in-the-field-problem-intersecting-circular-areas)

A farmer ties a cow with a rope to a pole at the edge of a round field of radius **r**. How long must the rope be compared to **r** if the farmer wants to ensure that the cow can roam exactly half of the field?

**The point is to find a [closed-form expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression), not solve this with numerical analysis etc. Is that possible?**

---

There's a nice depiction of the problem here:
_http://www11.speedyshare.com/files/25162122/download/Cow.png

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51/the-cow-in-the-field-problem-intersecting-circular-areas). The accepted answer there states that there is no closed-form solution.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoatProblem.html may also be useful.