# Find the area where dog can roam

Tags: geometry, area

A dog is tied to circular pillar by a rope. Radius of this pillar is $1m$ and length of rope is $\pi m$. What is an area where dog can roam?


I tried to find the area of all semicircles and then to find its sum. It is easy to find an area at front side of the pillar. It is $\displaystyle\frac12\pi^2\pi=\frac{\pi^3}{2}$. Problem is how to find remaining area. I tried to write this area using compass and straightedge, but I couldn't. Then I wrote this in AutoCAD and it looks like this:
[image: Area where dog can roams]
Is it possible to find the exact value of this area?

Comment: Is not the bottom portion an involute? It is, like the cycloid, easy to evaluate by integration.

Comment: Although, given that this question already has more votes and a complete answer, perhaps we should close that older question as a duplicate of this one...

Comment: Supplementary question. What's the area if the rope has arbitrary length L?

Comment: By the way, this is described as the [goat problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoatProblem.html) on MathWorld (don't be misled by the first diagram on the page; it deals with both the interior and the exterior cases).

Comment: You can find a few results searching for [bull tied circular silo](http://www.google.com/search?q=bull+tied+circular+silo) or some similar phrases. (You can try various animals.)

Comment: The length of the perimeter of the roaming area can also be calculated, and turns out to be equal to the circumference of the circle of radius $\pi$ - the same as if the pillar weren't there.

Comment: Got same result as MartinG

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942222/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Edit: redefined $\theta$ for simplicity and introduced $a$ for generality.]

Let $a$ be the radius of the pillar ($a=1$ in the example). The length of the rope is $L=\pi a.$

Let the length of the rope (assumed taut) not in contact with the pillar be $l(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle between a vertical line descending from the pillar centre (O) and a line between O and the rope's point of attachment. Then
$$
l = a\theta
$$
$\theta$ is also the angle of the rope measured from the horizontal.

The area swept out as the rope turns anticlockwise through angle increment $d\theta$ is
$$
dA = \tfrac{1}{2}l^2 d\theta
$$
The total area swept out in the lower right quadrant is therefore
$$
A = \int dA = \int_0^{\pi}\tfrac{1}{2}a^2\theta^2 d\theta = \tfrac{1}{6}\pi^3a^2
$$
Doubling up for the other side and adding the semicircular area at the top gives a total area of
$$
2 (\tfrac{1}{6}\pi^3a^2) + \tfrac{1}{2}\pi(\pi a)^2 = \tfrac{5}{6}\pi^3a^2
$$

Comment: Did you subtract the area of the pillar (where the dog cannot roam)?

Comment: No, but that wasn't necessary because it's not included in the calculation.

Comment: For a related physics problem, see http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/135325/giant-leap-of-the-space-goat