# A goat tied to a corner of a rectangle

Tags: geometry, contest-math, circles, area, rectangles

> A goat is tied to an external corner of a rectangular shed measuring 4 m by 6 m.  If the goat’s rope is 8 m long, what is the total area, in square meters, in which the goat can graze?

Well, it seems like the goat can turn a full circle of radius 8 m, and a rectangular shed's diagonal is less than 8m (actually √52), and so shouldn't it be just 6 x 4 = 24 sq metre? The answer says it is 53 pi, and I have no clue why it is so or why my way of solving doesn't work.

Updated:
Oh, and the only area given is that of the shed's. How can I know the full area in which the goat can actually graze on?

Comment: Hint: the goat is *outside* the shed. Draw a picture approximately to scale and look at the pieces.

Comment: The goat is outside of the shed, so it wraps around the shed.

Comment: Related, with a circle instead of the rectangle: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/928008 (related to [the goat problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoatProblem.html)).

Comment: "What is the total area, in square meters, in which the goat can graze?" Infinite. Reasoning: the very first thing the goat is going to do is get bored, figure out that the reason it can't wander freely is because of the stupid rope and collar, and will then either A) slip its head out of the collar, or B) chew through the rope. We raise goats.They have the problem-solving abilities of a 7-year-old human. Seriously - you don't confine a goat - you just convince it that it will have more fun/be better fed/have life easier "inside" than "outside". If a goat wants out, it will find a way.

Comment: `6 x 4` that's the area of the shed. The goat grazes *outside*  of the shed, not inside

Comment: The key word that you seem to have skipped over (as did I, when I first read this) is **external**.

Comment: The size of the field as delimted by its containing fence. Goats are quite capable of gnawing through rope.

Comment: @BobJarvis Are goats (and 7-year-old humans) capable of escaping orbit and exploring the whole universe as well?

Comment: "The goat is outside of the shed" In what world can a goat graze *inside* a shed? How can so many people miss this??  :p

Comment: @Stijn the shed is a greenhouse. Grass grows inside.

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga - please...don't give them ideas... :-)

Comment: How long is the neck of the goat? It adds to the circles :) unless the rope is tied to its mouth, in which case eating in general might become problematic.

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga As a simplifying assumption, we posit that the goat lives on an infinite, flat plane. ;-)

Answer (score 262, accepted):

Parts of three different circles.
[image]

Comment: Man, with that goat you have on the picture, you are definitely the winner of this post :D

Comment: You have a magically appearing $m^2$ in an equation.

Comment: Agree with Carsten, you should check your units. Other than that great answer :-).

Comment: Don't know what @CarstenS means by magically appearing m2.  The units are clearly in meters, so the area would be in squared meters.  Perhaps he/she means that the m is missing and should be included in your previous terms.  And +1 for the goat.

Comment: @amWhy,I myself didn't expect this much upvotes from these wonderful and kind people in here.

Comment: @Thomas  Oh, I know that.  This was not a criticism of your post, you did fine. It's just sometimes, the way this site works, and responds, is inconsistent.  That said, enjoy the ride!

Comment: @AgapwIesu This is math.SE, so I'm thinking it's because meters weren't in the rest of the equation in this answer (even if they are in the question)

Comment: Poor Thomas didn't get the full rep his goat drawing skills deserved.

Comment: Wow nice answer. Clear case of 'a picture says more than a thousand words'. I was subtracting the shed area from the full cirkel area but your picture shows very clearly why that is wrong. Great answer, +1!

Comment: @AgapwIesu: you can't write 53Pi = 166,5m²... your left hand would need m² as well :)

Comment: @AgapwIesu, isn't that clear where that 53 comes from? Isn't it the result of mxm?

Comment: A solution to the magically appearing square meters would be to stick them inside square brackets. Alternatively you can calculate everything with units written, but it gets unwieldy. Alternatively, I believe this notation is legit as well: $\frac{A}{m^2} = ...$

Comment: I'm going to wait until the UTC date turns to upvote this answer. You deserve every point. @AgapwIesu They mean the units should appear in all expressions of the equations, not just at the end. It's a great habit to be in if you do physics; it helps you spot mistakes.

Comment: @JanDvorak yeah, but especially with that notation the $m^2$ looks like you have some variable $m$. Never set units in italic font; $\frac{A}{\mathrm{m^2}}$ is the correct style.

Comment: I am sorry, I had thought my current would be clear enough without extra explanation. The answer of course still fully deserves an up-goat. It is just that as a mathematician I take equality signs quite seriously and therefore flinch at $53\pi=166.5m^2$, because it would follow that $\pi=3.1415m^2$. On the other hand I would not mind the following: “$A=53\pi\approx166.5$. The area that the goat can graze is $166.5{\rm m}^2$.” Just my two cents.

Comment: @CarstenS I would prefer throwing the units in from the beginning. [Dimensional analysis](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/31380/177).

Comment: Wow prettiest goat so far. +1

Comment: For units, do not italicize.  So $m^2$ is the square of something called $m$, but $\mathrm{m}^2$ means square meters.

Comment: Could we please keep the original goat?

Comment: @camden_kid, I would like to, but I am new in here and I really don't know  how exactly the system works in here. I woke up in the morning and I saw my drawing was changed due to some other peoples decision. That interfering could be acceptable If there was anything wrong with my calculations or violating the rules of the site but not deciding to modify my cartoon drawing. I have the original drawing and can upload it again only if that is not against the "edit suggestion approved" rules in here.

Comment: @Seyed Please upload it again and maybe put some text in the answer to tell people to stop changing the image. Great answer by the way.

Comment: @camden_kid, it is done.

Comment: Two small points: You cannot "let" $\pi$ equal anything; $\pi$ is what it is. The answer is slightly wrong. The correct way to calculate is to use the full accuracy of your calculator (which knows $\pi$ pretty accurately), and round the result to the desired number of decimal places only when stating it at the end.

Comment: I've made this diagram into a graph where you can vary the side of the shed and the length of the rope. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/icntkxirrl

Comment: It has been a while and the goat ate a door in the center of the closest 6m side so now you have to recalculate.

Comment: This is just wrong as it currently is, the area isn't equal to 166.50. It's $53 \pi$, or **approximately** 166.5 [m^2]

Answer (score -1):

$$\frac{3}{4}\pi 8^2+\frac{1}{4}\pi (8-6)^2+\frac{1}{4}\pi (8-4)^2=53\pi$$

Comment: An equation without a result and zero explanation isn't going to help anyone.