# Pasture in the field

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, solution-verification

Jhon horse was tied to a 10-meter-radius circular pasture. The stretched horse rope reached 15 m. How big is the horse able to graze?

[image]

My attemp: [[image]]

Correct?

Comment: Please read this [Mathjax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and try to write down your attempt instead of posting pictures . It would take some time , but your question will be better received by the community.

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit Sorry, but I'm using a very old phone. There is no way to use it

Comment: Does this helps you [the-cow-in-the-field-problem-intersecting-circular-areas?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51/the-cow-in-the-field-problem-intersecting-circular-areas?rq=1)?

Comment: you can't type dollar signs  and backslashes and english symbol names ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The cow in the field problem (intersecting circular areas)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51/the-cow-in-the-field-problem-intersecting-circular-areas)